# How to handle authentication popup when password contains '#'

Tags: selenium, basic-authentication

I want to handle authentication popup by passing username and password in url. Since password contains '#', I am not able to do it. Is there any way to do it?

I have handled it using autoit but I wanted to handle it using above method.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? I'm sure what you're asking for will solve your problem, but there may be a standard solution to the same, which addresses security without being a pain for the user.

Comment: To handle authentication popup we need to provide username and password in this way:   "http://" + login + ":" + password + "@" + url

Comment: Sounds like HTTP Basic Authentication, see [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters) for more background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sending a password via url seems like a bad idea, but if you must, [urlencode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) it. (Replace it with %23).

Comment: Definitely a bad idea for a variety of reasons. If you control the website an authentication token (like what you see in password reset emails) is somewhat better.